# Naming two kinds of scope in Java

Tags: java, c++, scope

I have difficulties in naming the two kinds of scopes that I see in Java:

```
class Fun {
    int f = 1;
    void fun() {
        int f = 2;
        while(true){
            int f = 3;
            int g = 1;
        }
        int g = 2;
    }
}
```

The case is mostly with `f = 3` and `g = 2`;

A `while` statement doesn't introduce a new scope, so I can't create a while-local variable named `f`. But if I create a local variable named `g` then I can "re-create" it after the loop. Why? I know it's no longer accessible, but if the compiler checks accessibility then it almost checks scopes..

So I was wondering what is the deal here, what are these concepts called? Is it the same as in C++?

---

I just managed to install g++ and tried it out myself:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int f = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<1; i++){
        int f = 1;
        cout << f << endl;
        {
            int f = 2;
            cout << f << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << f << endl;
}
```

So apparently C++ treats all scopes equally!

Comment: A while loop introduces a new scope, it can see everything above it, things above it can't see it

Comment: Every { introduces a new scope, including those after while statements.

Comment: OK, so why can I redeclare `f` in a method (there is an instance `f`) and I can't in a loop?

Comment: @user basically because doing so; makes the upper f unreachable (whereas a hidden field can be reached using this.f) And it is highly prone to causing surprising bugs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you left the while{} loop g went out of scope as soon as you left it. It was then valid to declare g again.

Local variables are only in scope for the duration of the block in which they are declared.

To go into more detail:

- The first `f` is object scope. Its accessible from the object at all
  times.
- The second `f` is local scope. You access it using `f`, you
  can still access the object scope `f` using `this.f`.
- The third `f` is trying to create a second local scope `f`. That is invalid.
- The first `g` is creating a local scope `g`.
- The second `g` is creating a second local scope `g` but the first one has already gone out of scope and disappeared.

So the only invalid declaration is the third f.

There is a third type of scope which is where static variables are declared - these are variables that are shared between every instance of a class.

There are a number of names for the types, some of the most common are Local Variables, Instance Variables (also known as Fields) and Class Variables (also known as Static Fields). You also have method parameters but that's just a different way of getting a Local Variable.

For further reading:

- http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html
- http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/4/lec/08

Comment: Ah... so what you're saying is that there are **exactly** 2 kinds of scopes in Java: object and local (are these the proper names?) Further, that only class declarations create object scopes.. Do I understand you correctly? 

Is it the same in ,say, C++ ?

Comment: I'll add a bit more :)

Answer (score 3):

In java it is forbidden to shadow variables from outer local scopes, IIRC. It's just "arbitrary" language rule, to prevent programmer from making some stupid mistakes. C# has same rule, IIRC, or even more strict (the last `g` might be error in C# because it was in scope in same method, not sure). C and C++ do not have this rule, though usually there is a compiler warning, depending on compiler and warning flags.

Every `{}` is a new block scope.

The last `g` does not shadow the earlier `g` because earlier one is not in scope any more. So it's ok.

The innermost `f` shadows the earlier local `f` which is still in scope, so not ok.

Class member variables are still accessible by using `this.` so it's ok to shadow them (though potentially misleading, esp. if IDE syntax highlighting does not highlight them differently).

Comment: I like your first sentence very much, it's clear and points out the arbitrarity... do you know how other languages (C++, JavaScript..) handle this? Plus, do you know the official names (if they exist) for those two kinds of scopes?

Comment: @user3073853 I'd have to dig out JLS to get the official names, but this sounds understandable: method scope for method and block scope for {} compund statement. Add "nested" or "inner"/"outer" as necessary to define scope relations.

Comment: @user3073853 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/ for the dirty details of exact terminology... :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Fun {
    int f = 1;// Its My f and i wont tell my fun() not to have 'f'
    void fun() {
        int f = 2; //Its my 'f' and till i own my 'f' i wont consider Fun Class 'f' also while 'f' 
        while(true){
            int f = 3; //Its my 'f' and he rules within me alone 
            int g = 1;
        }
        int g = 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The scope of a local variable declaration in a block is the rest of the block in which the declaration appears (JLS 6.3 Scope of a Declaration).

```
void fun() {  // block starts

   int f = 2; // f will be visible everywhere from fun() body

...

   {  // another block starts, it's legal even without while or for
      // f is visible, you cannot declare it again

      int g = 1; // will be visible till the end of the block

   }

   // g is invisible here because the block where it was declared ended
}
```